# walk (out) into the hallway

Tags: difference

1) An elevator arrived and a man walked out into the hallway.

2) An elevator arrived and a man walked into the hallway.

Is it correct or not to add "out" as in the first sentence?

Comment: It's OK either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the man walked out of the elevator, you must say that. Neither of your phrases would strictly mean that the man emerged from the elevator.
A sentence that would strongly suggest it is:
"An elevator arrived, its door opened, and a man stepped out into the hallway."